# Check if array contains value in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, node.js

On client side I have $scope.loggedInUser, which refers to mongoose user schema. Another schema I'm using is a conversation schema. Every user can join conversation, in that case he will be added to conversation.participants array, which is defined like that:

```
var conversationsSchema = new Schema({
    participants: {type: Array, default: []}
});
```

I want to display only conversation with current user (i.e. loggedInUser) in participants array. I tried

```
ng-repeat="conversation in conversations" ng-if="conversation.participants.indexOf(logged_in_user) > -1"
```

but I dodn't see any. How can I check if element exists in array in ng-if (or generally in angular) correctly?

Comment: Do you have the same definition of conversation obj and logged_in_user obj?

Comment: @SatyamKoyani conversation.participants is an array of users objects. The point of filtering is actually to find if one of the users in this array is a currently logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) like

```
ng-repeat="conversation in conversations | filter:logged_in_user"
```

I'm not sure if the view side implementation will dig into the nested collection, 
you might have to filter it in the controller

```
filteredConversations  = $filter(this.conversations,
{name:logged_in_user},doFiltering);
```

where do filtering is a method to do the actual work, something like:

```
function (actual, expected) {
return actual.participants.indexOf(expected) > -1;
}
```

be sure to inject $filter into your controller if you do it controller side.

Comment: here is it possible only through viewside ?